# Do-while loop won't stop after the while part gets false C#

Tags: c#, loops, exit, do-while

This is a part of a code which determines whether a number is prime or not. I know it could be solved in other ways, but I cant figure out why this loop wont stop if I put in a "5" as a number. The divisor reaches 5 after the third "divisor++;" (the divisor starts from 2) but the while loop wont quit.
Can anyone help me?

```
 do
            {
                if (number % divisor == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Number is not a prime.");
                }

                if (divisor == number - 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Number is prime.");
                }
                divisor++;
            } while (number % (divisor -1) != 0 || divisor != number);
```

Comment: Learn how to debug your code. It is the best way to understand your problem and how to solve it

Comment: Perhaps [this will help you](https://rextester.com/ULNI55101). In future, I recommend stepping through your code with the debugger, checking the values of the variables involved as you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition should probably be `... != 0 && divisor != number`.

Difference being && rather than ||.

Comment: But if I use `&&` both of the conditions would need to be false for the loop to stop. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Tommy Look at the [truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_conjunction_(AND)) for AND and OR.

Comment: @Tommy No, with `&&`, only one of the conditions needs to be false for the whole expression to be false, stopping the loop.

Comment: Oh, so the loop only stops, if the whole `(...)` is false after the `while`. And if one of them is true, and it was divided with `||` than the whole `(...)` will be true...

Answer (score 2):

while (number % (divisor -1) != 0 || divisor != number)

Above statement would never let it break.

For example if divisor is 5 then
5 % (5-1) would 1 and loop will continue

when divisor is 6 then

6 != 5 and it will continue

you should use

while (number % (divisor) != 0);

Comment: while will continue till condition is true. So 1 != 0, which is true so while will continue

Comment: Wait.. when the divisor reaches 5 and the condition is being checked, wont it check both conditions since they were divided by `||` ? So it checks if `5 % (5-1) != 0` and that turns out to be true, so it goes to the next condition which is `5 != 5` . And that one is false, so it should stop the loop.

Comment: no it will go to second condition only if first is false. OR operator means if either one of the conditions is true, so if first condition is true then there is no reason to check second. make sense?